# Websocket connection in Node.js closes on sending

Tags: node.js, windows, websocket, npm, send

I tried many different npm web socket libraries (WebSocket, ws, express-ws and more), and in EVERYONE of them I have the same problem. When I try to send a websocket message, the connection closes.
I have no problem receiving messeges, only sending.

Here is one simple example of one test with express and ws libraries:
Node.JS side:

```js
var server = require('http').createServer()
  , url = require('url')
  , WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server })
  , express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , port = 8080
  , fs = require('fs');

app.use(function (req, res) {
  var index = fs.readFileSync('./interface/index.html');
  res.end(index);
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  var location = url.parse(ws.upgradeReq.url, true);
  console.log('open ws');
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
    ws.send('test back');
  });

  ws.on('close', function () {
    console.log('ws connection closed.');
  })
});

server.on('request', app);
server.listen(port, function () { console.log('Listening on ' + server.address().port) });
```

and the browser side ("./interface/index.html"):

```js
window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
var port = 8080;
var ip = window.location.hostname;
var connection;

connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + ip + ':' + port);

connection.onopen = function () {
  // connection is opened and ready to use
  console.log('Web socket connection with', ip + ':' + port);
  //sendQueue(msgQueue);

};

connection.onerror = function (error) {
  // an error occurred when sending/receiving data
  console.log('Web socket erorr with', ip + ':' + port + ':', error);
};

connection.onmessage = function (message) {
  // try to decode json (I assume that each message from server is json)
  console.log("Received ws");
  // handle incoming message
};

connection.onclose = function (){
  console.log("Web socket connection lost.");
};

function sendws() {
  connection.send("test");
  console.log("sent ws");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Simple Web Socket test</title>
  <!--<meta name="description" content="Simple Web Socket">-->
  <meta name="author" content="Binoman">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="sendws()">Send</button>
</body>
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I updated Node.js to 6.7.
Running on windows 10.
I appreciate the help!
Thanks!

Comment: Your client side code is the same as server side.

Comment: Pasted it wrong. Sorry. I'll update it soon.

Comment: Where's the client code?

Comment: I updated the browser code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered it was my antivirus's web protection that blocked the connection. I made an exception for my localhost address and it working perfectly now.

Comment: Had exactly the same thing. Infurating! For information, I was using Kaspersky.